# Confused to why my UISCrollView's frame is null

Tags: iphone, ios

I started out with an empty project and added a view controller along with its nib. Inside the nib, there is a view with a UIScrollView as the view's child. Inside the scrollview, I have multiple assets like textfields, labels and buttons.

I am at the point where I want my scrollview to move up when the keyboard shows up. I looked up on stackoverflow on how to do this. I basically copied the code and tried to understand it. However, the view is still not moving up. So time for some debug statements....

My UIScrollView is hooked up (IBOutlet) to the RootViewController and is accessible from there. I tried printing out my scrollView (the instance name) and I got an object. However, when I tried printing out scrollView.frame.... I got null... does anyone have any idea to why this is?

Here is some code snippet with some of my debug statements

```
- (void) moveScrollView:(NSNotification *) notification up: (BOOL) upFlag{
    NSDictionary * userInfo = [notification userInfo];

    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
    CGRect keyboardEndFrame;

    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardEndFrame];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];

    CGRect newFrame = scrollView.frame;
    CGRect keyboardFrame  = [self.view convertRect:keyboardEndFrame toView:nil];
    NSLog(@"scrollView: %@", scrollView);
    NSLog(@"frame: %@", scrollView.frame);
    NSLog(@"Old Height: %@", scrollView.frame.size.height);

    newFrame.size.height -= keyboardFrame.size.height * (upFlag ? 1 : -1);
    NSLog(@"New Height: %@", newFrame.size.height);
    scrollView.frame = newFrame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void) keyboardShow:(NSNotification *) notification{
    NSLog(@"Keyboard Show");
    [self moveScrollView: notification up:YES];
}
```

[image: Nib]

Answer (score 3):

You can't print frame with %@. %@ prints Objective C objects; frame is not an Objective C object. It is a C struct, CGRect. Print its components individually like this:

```
NSLog(@"frame: (%0f %0f; %0f %0f)",
               scrollView.frame.origin.x, scrollView.frame.origin.y,
               scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

I think using the debugger is more effective. When in the debugger you can use

```
po object
```

to print Objective C objects, and

```
print (CGRect)[scrollView frame]
```

to print the frame.

By the way, the recommended method to adjust the scroll view for the keyboard in Apple's documentation is to set the content inset, not change the frame. I started out changing the frame too and had weird problems.

Comment: thanks so much for the pointer. I will see what I get with this.

Answer (score 1):

Print  the frame like

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromRect(frame));`
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the moveScrollView method is called when your view is loaded ?

Try to set a breakpoint in the -viewDidLoad method and make sure that it is called before your moveScrollView method.

Hope this helps,
Vincent

Comment: it is registered to the keyboardWIllShow notification